# HDF vs NoSQL solutions

Tags: database, data-structures, nosql, bigdata, hdf5

Hi I get a look in some scientific data stored in HDF5 format and I was wondering if there is any NoSQl solution that will reach the same performance in read/write as HDF5 .

The data of my example use a tree architecture ( /root then /root/key then /root/key/data_key ) so is it possible to find an open source NOSQl solution that use double key querying (Oracle NoSQL offer that possibility with a primary and minor key )?

If you have any idea or opinions about this subject in general do not hesitate to share them !

Thank you .

Answer (score 4):

Performance comparison always depend on your access pattern. So it is really difficult to provide numbers for the general case.

If you have a graph like structure and you want to query it you could try to use a graph database (i.e. [Neo4J](http://www.neo4j.org/)). (how deep is your hierarchy/tree structure?)

You can also think about splitting your data into a raw part and a meta-information part. 
The meta-information part can be stored in a NoSQL/RDBS database and the raw data in HDF5 files.